# Multiplication in Calculator Android App throwing alphabeta in output

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator

Below is the code for the Calculator Android App which I am making:

```
package com.example.calculator;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.lang.Math;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class main extends Activity {
    GridView mKeypadGrid;
    TextView userInputText;
    TextView memoryStatText;

    Stack<String> mInputStack;
    Stack<String> mOperationStack;

    KeypadAdapter mKeypadAdapter;
    TextView mStackText;
    boolean resetInput = false;
    boolean hasFinalResult = false;

    String mDecimalSeperator;
    double memoryValue = Double.NaN;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat
                .getInstance();
        char decimalSeperator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols()
                .getDecimalSeparator();
        mDecimalSeperator = Character.toString(decimalSeperator);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the stack
        mInputStack = new Stack<String>();
        mOperationStack = new Stack<String>();

        // Get reference to the keypad button GridView
        mKeypadGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdButtons);

        // Get reference to the user input TextView
        userInputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        userInputText.setText("0");

        memoryStatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMemory);
        memoryStatText.setText("");

        mStackText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStack);

        // Create Keypad Adapter
        mKeypadAdapter = new KeypadAdapter(this);

        // Set adapter of the keypad grid
        mKeypadGrid.setAdapter(mKeypadAdapter);

        // Set button click listener of the keypad adapter
        mKeypadAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btn = (Button) v;
                // Get the KeypadButton value which is used to identify the
                // keypad button from the Button's tag
                KeypadButton keypadButton = (KeypadButton) btn.getTag();

                // Process keypad button
                ProcessKeypadInput(keypadButton);
            }
        });

        mKeypadGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void ProcessKeypadInput(KeypadButton keypadButton) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, keypadButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String text = keypadButton.getText().toString();
        String currentInput = userInputText.getText().toString();

        int currentInputLen = currentInput.length();
        String evalResult = null;
        double userInputValue = Double.NaN;

        switch (keypadButton) {
        case BACKSPACE: // Handle backspace
            // If has operand skip backspace
            if (resetInput)
                return;

            int endIndex = currentInputLen - 1;

            // There is one character at input so reset input to 0
            if (endIndex < 1) {
                userInputText.setText("0");
            }
            // Trim last character of the input text
            else {
                userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(0, endIndex));
            }
            break;
        case SIGN: // Handle -/+ sign
            // input has text and is different than initial value 0
            if (currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput != "0") {
                // Already has (-) sign. Remove that sign
                if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                    userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(1,
                            currentInputLen));
                }
                // Prepend (-) sign
                else {
                    userInputText.setText("-" + currentInput.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
        case CE: // Handle clear input
            userInputText.setText("0");
            break;
        case C: // Handle clear input and stack
            userInputText.setText("0");
            clearStacks();
            break;
        case DECIMAL_SEP: // Handle decimal separator
            if (hasFinalResult || resetInput) {
                userInputText.setText("0" + mDecimalSeperator);
                hasFinalResult = false;
                resetInput = false;
            } else if (currentInput.contains("."))
                return;
            else
                userInputText.append(mDecimalSeperator);
            break;
        case DIV:
        case PLUS:
        case MINUS:
        case MULTIPLY:
            if (resetInput) {
                mInputStack.pop();
                mOperationStack.pop();
            } else {
                if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                    mInputStack.add("(" + currentInput + ")");
                } else {
                    mInputStack.add(currentInput);
                }
                mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
            }

            mInputStack.add(text);
            mOperationStack.add(text);

            dumpInputStack();
            evalResult = evaluateResult(false);
            if (evalResult != null)
                userInputText.setText(evalResult);

            resetInput = true;
            break;
        case CALCULATE:
            if (mOperationStack.size() == 0)
                break;

            mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
            evalResult = evaluateResult(true);
            if (evalResult != null) {
                clearStacks();
                userInputText.setText(evalResult);
                resetInput = false;
                hasFinalResult = true;
            }
            break;
        case M_ADD: // Add user input value to memory buffer
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                memoryValue = 0;
            memoryValue += userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();

            hasFinalResult = true;

            break;
        case M_REMOVE: // Subtract user input value to memory buffer
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                memoryValue = 0;
            memoryValue -= userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();
            hasFinalResult = true;
            break;
        case MC: // Reset memory buffer to 0
            memoryValue = Double.NaN;
            displayMemoryStat();
            break;
        case MR: // Read memoryBuffer value
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                return;
            userInputText.setText(doubleToString(memoryValue));
            displayMemoryStat();
            break;
        case MS: // Set memoryBuffer value to user input
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            memoryValue = userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();
            hasFinalResult = true;
            break;
        default:
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))) {
                if (currentInput.equals("0") || resetInput || hasFinalResult) {
                    userInputText.setText(text);
                    resetInput = false;
                    hasFinalResult = false;
                } else {
                    userInputText.append(text);
                    resetInput = false;
                }

            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private void clearStacks() {
        mInputStack.clear();
        mOperationStack.clear();
        mStackText.setText("");
    }

    private void dumpInputStack() {
        Iterator<String> it = mInputStack.iterator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            CharSequence iValue = it.next();
            sb.append(iValue);

        }

        mStackText.setText(sb.toString());
    }

    private String evaluateResult(boolean requestedByUser) {
        if ((!requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 4)
                || (requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 3))
            return null;

        String left = mOperationStack.get(0);
        String operator = mOperationStack.get(1);
        String right = mOperationStack.get(2);
        String tmp = null;
        if (!requestedByUser)
            tmp = mOperationStack.get(3);

        double leftVal = Double.parseDouble(left.toString());
        double rightVal = Double.parseDouble(right.toString());
        double result = Double.NaN;

        if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.DIV.getText())) {
            result = leftVal / rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MULTIPLY.getText())) {
            result = leftVal * rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.PLUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal + rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MINUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal - rightVal;
        }

        String resultStr = doubleToString(result);
        if (resultStr == null)
            return null;

        mOperationStack.clear();
        if (!requestedByUser) {
            mOperationStack.add(resultStr);
            mOperationStack.add(tmp);
        }

        return resultStr;
    }

    private String doubleToString(double value) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value))
            return null;

        long longVal = (long) value;
        if (longVal == value)
            return Long.toString(longVal);
        else
            return Double.toString(value);

    }

    private double tryParseUserInput() {
        String inputStr = userInputText.getText().toString();
        double result = Double.NaN;
        try {
            result = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }

        return result;

    }

    private void displayMemoryStat() {
        if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue)) {
            memoryStatText.setText("");
        } else {
            memoryStatText.setText("M = " + doubleToString(memoryValue));
        }
    }

}
```

When I give the inputs as 45454545454545 * 54545454545454, the output is shown as 2.479338842975157E27. I get some alphabet E in the output.

The multiplication code is:

```
  if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MULTIPLY.getText())) {
            result = leftVal * rightVal;
  }
```

Instead of E, I want to show the result as _______ * 10^x.
Can anyone help me how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The E shows it is the Exponent - it is normal, what are you aiming at?

Comment: @DaveGordon Instead of E, I want to show the result as _______ * 10^x, then how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about how to display the numbers.. so you can use `NumberFormat` to specify how the number should be displayed, e.g.:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

For more info:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Here is a good example: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/14/numberformat-class-android-rounding-number-android-formatting-decimal-values-android/

If you want to keep it as it is and just want replace the exponential `E` with `^`, why not try:

```
string.replace("E", "^")
```

Answer (score 0):

guess it is like in every calculator!

The E stands "for times ten to the power of"

So it is 10^27 * yourresult, so it is not an error!

Comment: So If I want to show the result as _______ * 10^27, then how to fix it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html  Use the pattern you need. If it isnt working this way, just take your value to string, substring it at 'E' remove the dot, in your result, count the digits and add zeros according to the number ob the substring.